# What is the difference between `tf.constant(0, SHAPE)` and `tf.zeros(SHAPE)`

Tags: tensorflow

They all yield ops.Tensor back to me. The difference seems just to be name and dtype. Are they all constant?

Thanks for answering in advance!

Comment: See [Constants, Sequences, and Random Values](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/constant_op#Constant_Value_Tensors). The former is just more flexible.

Comment: I see. So, they are actually the same thing, given the exact parameters. Maybe `tf.zeros` is just a shortcut of `tf.constant`.

Comment: If you want to check out the implementations, you can dive into the *Defined in ...* links in the docs.